# Manuscript formatting details

Tags: creative-writing

Someone, please provide the following details of the manuscript.

- Font style
- Font size
- Margins
- Number of words per page
- Spacing between lines

**Note:** Though this question seems to be a duplicate, I need the updated info.

Answer (score 4):

Your question probably needs to be more specific.

If your manuscript is to be submitted to an agent or publishing house formatting specifications can usually found in their submission guidelines.

Traditionally:

- Font Style: Times New Roman or Courier.
- Font Size: 10 or 12 pt
- Margins: 1" to 1.25" or 30mm
- Number of words per page: Redundant question! - Words per page is dictated by Font Style / Font Size / Margin Size / Line Spacing.
- Line spacing: Double Spaced.

However, most the above information has become moot. The specifications are designed for printed manuscripts. Very few establishments accept printed manuscripts. Large margins and double spaced lines allow for the manual insertion of comments and notes. With the advent of electronic submissions popular software utilises revision tools.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just need a very basic reference.

Comment: Many science fiction, fantasy, and mystery magazines still want manuscripts in this standard form, even with electronic submissions.

Answer (score 0):

For manuscript: (depends on what editor wants, but this is usually fine)
Font size: 12 pt
Font: Times New Roman
Margins: 1 inch. Just use standard 8.5x11 MS word document.
Number of words per page: irrelevant
Spacing: double

For book:
Font size: 12 pt
Font: Times New Roman
Margins and interior formatting: https://forums.createspace.com/en/community/docs/DOC-1482
Number of words per page: depends on the size of your book. I suggest going with 6x9. This is the most widely used.
Spacing: single